# how i can write $(this) about use javascript in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use this code correctly in JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll(".sided-sections .widget").forEach(function(a){ 
  var e = document.querySelector(this);
})
```

and thank you very much

Comment: That code already ***is*** Javascript.

Comment: What errors are you running into? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would simply use this code `$(this)` using javascript

Comment: Are you getting mixed up between pure JavaScript and jQuery? `$(this)` is jQuery and it's not clear how or why you want to use it. If you want to use jQuery, you have to include the jQuery library in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function $(selector){
    if(selector.startsWith("#")){
         return document.querySelector(selector);
    }else{
         return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
}

console.log($("#id").innerHTML);
```

You can define short function $(like jQuery $) in your script if you don't want to include jQuery.